# Hosting your own Microblog, Twitter style. What Software is available?

Tags: hosting, twitter

I think Twitter can be useful inside companies, for daily work: **To have a low profile way of communication**, for example within a team of developers who don't necessarily all work on the very same codebase but still share a common infrastructure or even libraries, they can just twitter from time to time what they are doing and everybody is up to date in a very informal, easy manner.

Twittering what one is currently doing could potentially avoid any overlap work as everybody is sort of informed about what is going on "in the cloud", without the negative of distraction from one to one communication, like telephone, email or talk.

If something interesting or something to ones own work related "twitters by", one can decide to hook in and engage in more direct communication.

So much for the motivation. I am now looking for a good solution to host in house for a dedicated private group of members.

The product should provide/have:

- size limited tweets
- have management interface to add/remove members
- allow multiple groups
- statistics
- have a persistent history
- easy to operate (cheap)
- media attachments would be great
- have great clients :-)
- last but not least, it **must be hosted in house**

Any experience you have to share on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 4):

I know some people who are currently experimenting with [StatusNet](http://status.net/).

It [seems to meet](http://status.net/wiki/Main_Page) some of your requirements (size limited tweets, groups, history, easy to use, and installable in house).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the list in [**this blog post**](http://www.web-strategist.com/blog/2008/09/08/list-of-enterprise-microblogging-tools-twitter-for-the-intranet/).  Something there might get you started.

Answer (score 0):

How about http://www.revou.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I see three options here:

- [StatusNet](http://status.net) (former Laconica) is a microblogging software being identi.ca the biggest implementation of this software
- OpenAtrium, is an intranet version of Drupal, it has [microblogging features](http://openatrium.com/features)
- [Prologue](http://p2theme.com/) is a Wordpress Theme that resembles Twitter